# How can I remove character elements from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to convert a line from a text file into a list. The contents of the test file are:

1 2 3 4 f g

I have read the contents into a list lst = ['1','2','3','4','f','g']. I want to remove 'f' and 'g' (or whatever characters they may be) and convert all the remaining elements to int type. How can I achieve this?

Comment: make use of str.isdigit() and int()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing, rather build a *new* list. Python is more efficient when just *appending* items to a list. Here we try to convert `i` to an `int` - if it is convertable then it reads as some base-10 number, with possible + or - sign. If it does not match, then `int(i)` throws a `ValueError` exception which we just ignore. Those values that were correctly converted will be appended to a new `result` list.

```
result = []
for i in elements:
    try:
        result.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good time for a list comprehension.  Convert to int only if isnumeric()

```
arr = [int(x) for x in arr if x.isnumeric()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if each character can be converted into a character:

```py
arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', 'f', 'g']
for c, char in enuemrate(arr[:]):
    try: 
      arr[c] = int(char)
    except ValueError:
      del arr[c]
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Python method **isalpha()**.
The method returns “True” if all characters in the string are alphabets, Otherwise, it returns “False”.
I'm assuming that there are no alpha-numeric elements in your list, and your list contains either digits or alphabets. You could try something like this:

```
elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'f', 'g']
for element in elements:
    if element.isalpha():
       elements.remove(element) #Removing the alphabets
#Converting the remaining elements to int
elements = [ int(x) for x in elements ]
```